# Как вывести ключ, созданные функцией?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Вот код:

```
const [letters, setLetters] = useState('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789')
    const [key, setKey] = useState('');

    const randomKeyGenerator = () => {
        let word = '';

        for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            word += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length));
        }

        const test = word.substring(0, 5) + '-' + word.substring(5, 10) + '-' + word.substring(10, 15);
        setKey(test.toUpperCase());

    };


    return (
        <Panel>
            <Text>Здесь будет ключ:</Text>
            <Button onClick={randomKeyGenerator}>тыык</Button>
        </Panel>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто добавить вывод нужной переменной в render

```
return (
        <Panel>
            <Text>Здесь будет ключ: {key}</Text>
            <Button onClick={randomKeyGenerator}>тыык</Button>
        </Panel>
    );
```